# How to set max of y axis on bar chart

Tags: bar-chart

I tried many solutions which were about similar question, but nothing helped... I have a bar chart in Latex, which contains values from 2 550 to 18 016. I want to have numbers on y axis: 0, 5 000, 10 000, 15 000, 20 000. But I have problem, that instead of 20 000 there is strange number 16 384 (I want to have 20 000 there) and also 10^4 (I dont want to see this number). Is there any easy solution for this?
My current code is:

```
    \begin{axis}[
title = Počet matchupov,
ybar,
nodes near coords, bar width=0.4cm,
symbolic x coords={PvZ, TvZ, PvT, TvT, PvP, ZvZ},
yticklabel = {\pgfmathparse{\tick*10000}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}},  y grid style={dashed,black!60},
        ymajorticks=true,
        ymin=0, ymax=20000,
        ytick style={black},]
\addplot coordinates{(PvZ, 18016)(TvZ, 14531)(PvT, 17385)(TvT, 2550)(PvP, 7015)(ZvZ, 6149)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: My bar chart currently looks like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to this site. If you want answers, you have to post an MME that starts with `\documentclass{...}` and ends with `\end{document}`

In the `PGFPLOTS manual` (version 1.18.1) the section 4.15.3 Tick Scaling – Common Factors In Ticks, we can see :

```
/pgfplots/scaled ticks=true|false|base 10:<e>|real:<num>|manual:{<label>}{<hcode<} (initially true)
```

- With `scaled ticks=false` your problem is solved.
- With `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/set thousands separator={\ }}` for space as thousands separator

**The code**

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/697223/how-to-set-max-of-y-axis-on-bar-chart
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/set thousands separator={\ }}%<-- this line
\begin{axis}[
    scaled ticks=false,%<--- this line
    title = Počet matchupov,
    ybar,
    nodes near coords, bar width=0.4cm,
    symbolic x coords={PvZ, TvZ, PvT, TvT, PvP, ZvZ},
    y grid style={dashed,black!60},
    ymajorticks=true,
    ymin=0, ymax=20000,
    ytick style={black},]
  \addplot coordinates{(PvZ, 18016)(TvZ, 14531)(PvT, 17385)(TvT, 2550)(PvP, 7015)(ZvZ, 6149)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer (+1)! I took a liberty and correct mark-up of codes in text as well correct some spelling error. If you not liked this, you may revert answer in original form

Comment: @Zarko Thank you twice, for your comment and for making the corrections.